Any downsides in changing PEM-formatted certificate's .pem extension to .cer?
I have a .pem file that contains only (one) certificate – no private key. To signal this fact, (I think) it'd be better to change the extension from .pem to .cer (or .crt). Are there any downsides?
Since it's all (ASCII) plaintext, I assume the answer is 'no', but would appreciate your opinion.

Renaming the file will require you to update the configuration of any applications that reference the old file name in their conf files. But you’re right that frequently in Linux file name extensions are there only for a human operator and not important at all for an application. If a different file name extension makes more sense to you, go for it.
